# What does the locus of $M$ form?

Tags: geometry, circles

Let $A$ and $B$ be two fixed points on a fixed straight line. Two circles touch this line at $A$ and $B$ respectively and tangent to each other at $M$. When the circles vary, what does the locus of $M$ form?

Comment: From your previous questions that I've glanced at, it seems that you don't tell us what you've tried. We don't encourage that on Math SE because it is difficult for us to give the appropriate help when we don't know what you already know or what you've tried, so we won't be able to guide you as well. For subsequent questions, it would be good if you include even a brief outline of the main approaches you have tried.

Comment: @user21820 That is not completely true. If you go through all my questions. You will find that there is 'my approach' paragraph included in many of the questions. You are actually talking about those questions in which I have not been able to proceed at all.

Comment: Well I would still suggest that you try to show us at least something that you tried, whether in your rough work or in your head. In this problem for example, if you had drawn a few pairs of circles for the same $(A,B)$ even with estimation, or if you had used a drawing software like Geogebra, you would have been able to guess the answer, and you should then tell us that guess, and perhaps any other things you suspect even if you cannot prove them.

Comment: Anyway I had given you an answer, in which I try to give barely enough to enable you to figure out the details. If you succeed, great! If not, then feel free to ask on specific statements. But based on the level of this geometry question I think you would be better off playing with Geogebra or some other geometry software to get a feel for what is happening before looking at any solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a circle. Observe that each of the two circles is perpendicular to the circle $C$ with diameter $AB$, because each is perpendicular to $C$ at $A$ or $B$ respectively. This means that for them to be tangent they have to intersect $C$ at the same point besides $A$ or $B$ respectively. Hence $M$ is on $C$, and clearly all points on $C$ are achievable if we allow degenerate circles with radius $0$ or $\infty$.