# The Locus Of M (Repeated Questuon)

Tags: geometry, circles

Let A and B be two fixed points on a straight line. Two circles touch this line at A and B respectively and the tangent to each other at M, when the circles vary the locus of M is?

This question has already been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792972/what-does-the-locus-of-m-form), but I could not comprehend that answer properly, also I am not allowed to comment on that answer as I don't have 50+ reputation. I have only drawn the rough sketch but not able to go any further.

Comment: But you could a) link this question to the previous version (and vice versa) to avoid unnecessary duplication of efforts and b) indicate what part of the answer to the other question you don't understand (since otherwise there's not much to be done but to repeat the answer).

Comment: [This is probably the question mentioned.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792972/what-does-the-locus-of-m-form) (The phrasing is completely identical. Of course, there could be something almost-like it somewhere around here.)

Comment: Exact dup of a question which should itself be closed... Wow.

Comment: @joriki I just hyperlinked the previous question, but how does it prevent duplication, I was sure it would be called a duplicate question, but because I couldn't comment in the old post, putting up a duplicate question was my only way. Of course, I should have mentioned how far I had made thru the question more clearly (like I had made a few sketches, but didn't upload them, that's my fault) and I'm also sorry I didn't clarify that I was stuck at the extreme cases and couldn't find a locus  joining the extreme cases, I really like the idea of preventing redundancy in this site, my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The locus of $M$ is the circle $\Gamma$ diameter $AB$.

Any circle $\Gamma_B$ touching the line $AB$ at $B$ is orthogonal to $\Gamma$ at $B$ and hence also at its other point of intersection (by reflection in the line $OO_B$). Call this point $M$. $OM$ is tangent to $\Gamma_B$ at $M$.

Let the bisector of $\angle AOM$ meet at $O_A$ the perpendicular to $AB$ at $A$. Then $O_AM$ is equidistant from $OA$ and $OM$, so the circle centre $O_A$ touching $AB$ at $A$ also touches the circle $\Gamma_B$ at $M$.

[image]